# Unable to Download Second file when First One is in Progress

Tags: java, android, json, download, threadpoolexecutor

I am able to Download one file at a time, but when I try to download another file if first one is in progress then download does not starts. The Second file download start only when first one is finished. I want to download two or more files at a time.

```
private class Downloader extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Displays the progress bar for the first time.
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 4, false);

        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // Update progress
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, values[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            String streamingUrl = new String(retVidUrl.trim()
                    .replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
                    .replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28")
                    .replace(")", "%29").replace("!", "%21")
                    .replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
                    .replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23")
                    .replace("$", "%24").replace("'", "%27")
                    .replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
                    .replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F")
                    .replace(":", "%3A").replace(";", "%3B")
                    .replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
                    .replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C")
                    .replace("]", "%5D").replace("_", "%5F")
                    .replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
                    .replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));

            String fStream = Uri.decode(streamingUrl);

            if (fStream != null) {

                System.out
                        .print("This is the final url from wherer you can download"
                                + fStream);
                ;

                URL u = null;
                InputStream is = null;

                try {
                    u = new URL(fStream);
                    is = u.openStream();
                    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u
                            .openConnection();// to know the size of video
                    size = huc.getContentLength();
                    System.out
                            .println("Seeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee here >>>>>>"
                                    + size);

                    if (huc != null) {
                        String mp44 = "mp4";
                        String fileName = size + "." + mp44;
                        // String fileName = "videoplayback.mp4";
                        // String storagePath =
                        // Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        String storagePath = Environment
                                .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                                + "/" + "Download";

                        File f = new File(storagePath, fileName);

                        fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len1 = 0;
                        Long downloadedSize = (long) 0;

                        if (is != null) {
                            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                downloadedSize += len1;
                                publishProgress((int) (downloadedSize * 100 / size));

                                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);

                            }
                        }
                        if (fos != null) {
                            fos.close();
                        }

                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error Msg", e.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error Msg", e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a side note regarding your massive `.replace(..)` chain. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Comment: Could you please post the code how you actually execute the `AsyncTask`? Which Android version are you targeting?

Comment: i am using 11 as min and 21 as max in manifest

Comment: Yes you can see i have edited my code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void>{
    private NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;
    String fileName;
    String filePath;
    public DownloadTask(Context context){
        mNotificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Create the notification in the statusbar
        mNotificationHelper.createNotification("" + _file_name + ".doc".toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        //This is where we would do the actual download stuff
        //for now I'm just going to loop for 10 seconds
        // publishing progress every second

        try {
            // connecting to url
            URL u = new URL(_file_url);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            fileName = "" + _file_name + ".doc".toString();
            // lenghtOfFile is used for calculating download progress
            int lenghtOfFile = c.getContentLength();

            // this is where the file will be seen after the download
            File file=new File(rootDir+ "/Apostolic/", fileName);
            String filePath=file.getPath();

            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(rootDir
                    + "/Apostolic/", fileName));
            // file input is from the url


            InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

            // here's the download code
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            long total = 0;

            while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                total += len1; // total = total + len1
                publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
            }
            f.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(_context, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("DP", ""+e);
        }

        for (int i=10;i<=100;i += 10)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress(i);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        //This method runs on the UI thread, it receives progress updates
        //from the background thread and publishes them to the status bar
        mNotificationHelper.progressUpdate(progress[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)    {
        //The task is complete, tell the status bar about it
        mNotificationHelper.completed(_file_name,filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain what your code does. In that way, more people will be able to receive benefit. :)

Comment: Can you tell me what is the benefit of your code ?? because you did not explained that whats happening , can i download two or more file at one time ??

Comment: My code is for downloading mp4 file from the server and store in external memory of mobile phone

Comment: This process is only for downloading file at a time , not for multiple files at a time ....